# Two loops and presentation of answer in a simple distribution format

Tags: r

There are 10 families. When they give birth to a boy they stop. When they have a girl they will keep giving birth. What is the ratio of boys to girls? I am able to do this part. The code is as per below.

```
N <- 10
boys <- 0
girls <- 0
while (N>=1) {
  boyorgirl <- sample (c("boy", "girl"), N, replace = TRUE)   
  boys <- boys + length(which(boyorgirl=="boy"))
  girls <- girls + length(which(boyorgirl=="girl"))
  N <- length(which(boyorgirl=="girl"))
}
ratioboygirl <- boys / girls
```

My problem comes when I have to repeat this for 1000 times for 1000 different families of 10. I am supposed to get 1000 different ratios of boys:girls and then to list the distribution of these 1000 ratios for easy viewing.

My own attempt is as per below. The code does not work and it also does not include placing the final 1000 ratios in a simple distribution format for ease of viewing.

```
boys <- list()
girls <- list()
ratioboygirl <- list()

for (ii in 1:1000) {
  boys[ii] <- 0
  girls[ii] <- 0
  N <- 10
  while (N>=1) {
    boyorgirl <- sample (c("boy", "girl"), N, replace = TRUE)   
    boys[ii] <- boys[ii] + length(which(boyorgirl=="boy"))
    girls[ii] <- girls[ii] + length(which(boyorgirl=="girl"))
    N <- length(which(boyorgirl=="girl"))
  }
  ratioboygirl[ii] <- boys [ii] / girls [ii]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you initialized `boys`, `girls` and `ratioboygirl` as `lists` you need to pass individual numbers using double brackets `[[]]` than a single bracket `[]` which passes a list instead. You can verify this using a simple example.

```r
a <- list(1,2,3)
a[1] + a[2]
#Error in a[1] + a[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
a[[1]] + a[[2]]
#[1] 3
```

You can also use `str(a[1] + a[2])` and `str(a[[1]] + a[[2]])` to see what each returns. The first returns a `list` whereas the second a `num`. Similarly you can modify your code as follows to get the output you want. The `unlist` converts the output which is a `list` to `num` to produce a similar output to your first script.

```r
set.seed(777)

boys <- list()
girls <- list()
ratioboygirl <- list()

for (ii in 1:10) {
  boys[[ii]] <- 0
  girls[[ii]] <- 0
  N <- 10
  while (N>=1) {
    boyorgirl <- sample (c("boy", "girl"), N, replace = TRUE)   
    boys[[ii]] <- boys[[ii]] + length(which(boyorgirl=="boy"))
    girls[[ii]] <- girls[[ii]] + length(which(boyorgirl=="girl"))
    N <- length(which(boyorgirl=="girl"))
  }
  ratioboygirl[[ii]] <- boys [[ii]] / girls [[ii]]
}
ratioboygirl_out<- unlist(ratioboygirl)

# ratioboygirl_out
#[1] 0.5263158 0.6250000 2.5000000 2.5000000 1.6666667 0.5555556 0.7692308
# [8] 0.6250000 0.7692308 0.8333333
```

Change the `10` to the number you like (`1000`).

Comment: and I will use the histogram function to finalize the output as per my own question. Thank you deepseefan for your advice.